Enable local cache of spring session which is persisted in redis
I am working on a spring web application where I am implementing the SSO using spring security and I am using the redis as the database to persist the session data. I got this part working, however,  now I would like to enable a local cache for the session data. The idea is to first do a lookup in local cache, if not available in local cache, only then try to read from remote redis. I looked through the documentation for spring session and the lettuce client, I could not find a clear documentation on how this could be implemented. Can you help with this? Below is my current redis configuration class
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableRedisHttpSession()
public class RedisConfig {

@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(31820);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setUsername("user");
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword("password");
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(0);

    LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();

    String pemCertificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            + "lorem lipsum"
            + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    X509Certificate certificate = CertificateUtils.convertPemToX509Certificate(pemCertificate);
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("redisServerCert", certificate);        
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    SslOptions sslOptions = SslOptions.builder()
                                .sslContext(contextBuilder -> contextBuilder.trustManager(trustManagerFactory))
                                .build();

    ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
                                    .sslOptions(sslOptions)
                                    .protocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.RESP3)
                                    .build();

    lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder
                                    .clientOptions(clientOptions)
                                    .useSsl()
                                    .disablePeerVerification();

    LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder.build();
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration);
}
}

I was trying to create a bean of type io.lettuce.core.support.caching.CacheFrontend as mentioned here How to configure client side caching in Lettuce 6 Spring Boot 2.4 however while trying this it was giving exception about no bean of type StatefulRedisConnection.

AFAIK the client-side caching feature for Redis is not integrated with the spring-session. Which means that any solution would be more of a workaround.
However the Redis Indexed Web Session is subscribed - by default - to Redis keyspace events, which would mean that whenever the session expires or is deleted you would be notified and could subscribe to the respective event.
See Understanding How Spring Session Cleans Up Expired Sessions for more details.
So a possible solution could be to implement a local cache (perhaps use some 3rd party implementation) and then hook the events to the cache.
